# Where do I call OpenGL initialize() function in Win32?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I've created a window for an **OpenGL (GLEW)** application that currently draws and updates the standard colored cube (in immediate mode). What I'm having trouble with is where to call the `initialize()` function, because I'm trying to use shaders.

```
int szWindow::WinLoop(MSG msg)
{
    while (isRunning)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {       
            // Application loop here
            renderClass->Update();          
            renderClass->Render();

            SwapBuffers(hDC);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: GLEW and OpenGL are two separate things, the former heavily depending on the latter. You cannot call `glewInit()` *before* a valid context has been create because `GLEW` uses GL functions which will simply crash the application without a valid context. Also, I'm not sure what `initialize()` function you're talking about. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score -1):

I think this isn't the best way to start. I would recommend use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/). You don't need to care about open the OpenGL context. But if you really wanna do it by yourself, begin with the [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context).

About the GLEW, no secrets: `glewInit()`.

Remember for OpenGL in Windows you gotta open the GL context (with GLFW or by yourself) and load the OpenGL extension (with GLEW or by yourself).

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestion of thokra, I updated this answer in case of someone else needs it. My first advice was to use NeHe just to open the context, but, in fact, [OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context) is much better for the modern OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ditched this program and moved to what you just said and trying to create a glfw3/glew application. Right now, I'm just getting LNK2019 errors for ever glfw call from their Hello World example

Comment: -1 for suggesting NeHe. Use the OpenGL wiki (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context). NeHe is wildly outdated and has been loathed for a long time by the OpenGL community and since the OP mentioned wanting to use shaders, NeHe is not a good place.

Comment: for opening the GL context, NeHe is just fine. what is the problem?